# Converting a mvc application to .net4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I have an MVC web application in asp.net 3.5 How can I convert that to asp.net4? Everywhere I read tells me to use a conversion wizard, well no conversion wizard starts when I open the project in vs. Can I manually start the wizard?

I am using vs 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also just Right click the project in Solution Explorer -> Property Pages -> Change the Target Framework

Comment: this.  the conversion wizard only really shows up when the solution/project needs to be upgraded.

Comment: From what I read if you do this it will not update everything in the web.config file that the wizard will do for you.

Comment: @nathan gonzalez...I want to upgrade it. that what I am trying to figure out. I created the application in 3.5 on my machine using vs 2010. Now we are switching to 4 so I need to upgrade it.

Comment: @twal, do you mean that you need to upgrade to mvc 3 *and* .net 4?  i don't know that the .net 4 really needs web.config changes.